# NodeJS: need to obtain reference to existing server or to close it

Tags: node.js

Ok - so there is something I am unable to find and I feel might be fairly simple.
I created a server but forgot to capture the reference sent back in a variable.

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    // Send the HTTP header
    // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
    // Content Type: text/plain
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    // Send the response body as "Hello World"
    response.end('Hello World\n');
 }).listen(8081);
```

Now I am trying to close the server but i don't have a reference to the server.
Is there any way to obtain the reference or close the http server from the nodejs interpreter to avoid using taskmanager to kill the process. Working on Win 7 NodeJS interpreter.

Creating a new one is not allowed.

```
 const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
..     // Send the HTTP header
..     // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
..     // Content Type: text/plain
..     response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
..
..     // Send the response body as "Hello World"
..     response.end('Hello World\n');
..
..  }).listen(8081, () => {
..
..     console.log("closing the server in 5 seconds");
..
..     setTimeout(() => server.close(), 5000);
..
..  });
ndefined
 Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8081
   at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
   at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
   at Server._listen2 (net.js:1252:14)
   at listen (net.js:1288:10)
   at Server.listen (net.js:1384:5)
   at repl:10:4
   at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:32:31)
   at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)
   at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:31:12)
   at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:308:29)
```

Comment: Use Ctrl+C to kill the server process? If I'm not mistaken, the server will be running in the main thread of the interpreter anyway, so the interpreter will block until you kill the server anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close it using [server.close();](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback) or just kill the process with Ctrl-C.

[http.createServer](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) returns the server, so assign the return value to a variable/constant and then you can reference the server.

```
const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    // Send the HTTP header
    // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
    // Content Type: text/plain
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    // Send the response body as "Hello World"
    response.end('Hello World\n');

 }).listen(8081, () => {

    console.log("closing the server in 5 seconds");

    setTimeout(() => server.close(), 5000);

 });
```

Comment: Actually i have already created the server but never captured the reference by mistake that is i forgot to write the "const server = " part. So now how do i get that reference.

Comment: @ManFriday if you started the process without that reference, you just can't, You need to restart the process with the modifications... If you want to kill an already running server, just kill it from the process list, or `ctrl-c` if it's in the foreground.

Comment: Ok - did that - but it also killed the interpreter. But the Ctrl+C works well and this code is absolutely fine - thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome :). Just so you know `listen EADDRINUSE :::8081` error is that you already have a process listening to that port, 8081. In your case was the other server that was already running.